# Enable button if input of type number or type file are filled

Tags: jquery

I need to enable some button only if other input are filled, and this is working for the input of type text, but not for the inputs of type number and file.

**See the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sappe/1ftLu3jk/3/**

Why it's not working? Input fields of type number or type file don't have a length?

Jsp:

```
<input type="file" id="file"/>
<input type="button" id="load-file" value="submit"/>
<br/>
<input type="number" id="insertAnno"/>
<input type="button" id="whenCustom" value="submit"/>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="text"/>
<input type="button" id="textInput" value="submit"/>
```

Js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#load-file').attr('disabled',true);

    $('#file').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length !=0){
            $('#load-file').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#load-file').attr('disabled', true);        
        }
    });

    $('#whenCustom').attr('disabled',true);

    $('#insertAnno').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length !=0){
            $('#whenCustom').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#whenCustom').attr('disabled', true);        
        }
    });

    $('#textInput').attr('disabled',true);

    $('#text').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length !=0){
            $('#textInput').attr('disabled', false);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#textInput').attr('disabled', true);        
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They've a lenght, but not an onkeyup event. Just change the events to `.change()` instead of `.keyup()`:

```
$('#insertAnno').change(...
$('#file').change(...
```

and both will work.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't think of this possibility